# Get #anchor for URL using jQuery ?

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#red-products").hide();  
    $("#content-info").click(function(event){
        $("#red-products").hide();  
        $("#red-information").show(); 
    });

    $("#content-product").click(function(event){
        $("#red-information").hide();
        $("#red-products").show();  
    });

    $("#more").click(function(event){
        load(this.href);
        return false;
    });

});
```

As you can see, by default `#red-products` is hidden and `#red-information` is visible. Sometimes I want `#red-products` to be visible and `#red-information` hidden, meaning something like

`http://localhost/networks2/profile.php?id=1&offset=1#products`

to show `#red-products` and hide `#red-information`. And

`http://localhost/networks2/profile.php?id=1&offset=1#information`

to hide `#red-products` and show `#red-information`.

How can I read anchor from URL using jQuery, and hide/show appropriate sections?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can change the initial hide to be based on [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location), by replacing this:

```
$("#red-products").hide();
```

With this:

```
$("#red-products, #red-information").hide();
$("#red-" + (window.location.hash.replace("#", "") || "information")).show();
```

This will hide both initially, then show the hasd (`#red-hashhere`), or default to showing `#red-information` as you have now.

Comment: @Adam - that's not a very helpful description :) what isn't working...and are you using the URLs exactly as you have in the question?