# Use ajax based on wordpress permalinks

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Im trying to create ajax calls based on wordpress permalinks.

Ex. domain.com/#!/tag/lorem-ipsum/

Using this url how can i read the hash and use it to do an ajax call that returns all posts for this specific tag?

Thanks

Comment: Didnt try because don't know the best method. Trying to get some guidance or to know if this is possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First read out the hash of the given url, [Get #anchor for URL using jQuery ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483044/get-anchor-for-url-using-jquery)
- Make an ajax call: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins.
- Fetch the posts with [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).
- Return the posts in the ajax response.
- Insert the posts in the HTML using javascript.

A way to get you started.