# jQuery (HTML?) display based on URL

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get #anchor for URL using jQuery ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483044/get-anchor-for-url-using-jquery)

I have seen in many sites the given URL is something like `http://mysite.com/index.php#something`. What the site displays differs from that `#something`. If it's there, we get something else, if it's not, then we get the default page.

I have no idea how this can be done and I am seeking knowledge. Can this be done via HTML only? Or do I need javascript/jquery?

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

Now that I have understood the concept of `#something` aka hash, how can I make it display something if it's hidden with css (`display: none;`), if the hash is for example `#contact`, then I want my index.php to display the contact page which is hidden?

Answer (score 2):

`#something` would link to a named anchor tag in the page, e.g.

```
<a name="something">...</a>
```

This typically will have the browser scroll to the anchor tag and display the content on that part of the page.

If you want to conditionally change content in the browser, depending on the text specified (such as `#something`), then you will need to use Javascript.

Comment: Yes, it's an anchor, and it doesn't require any javascript to use.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a url hash

You can get it in javascript by executing:

```
window.location.hash
```

You can even set it:

```
window.location.hash = "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

That #something will make the page to scroll to the element with that id(#something) when you are on that URL. It has nothing to do with javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

First, the **#something** that you said is known as **hash**

This hash could access by javascript, so you can do vary thing with this like the variable.